# Multiline values in cucumber datatables

Tags: datatable, cucumber, bdd, multiline, feature-file

I was wondering if anyone has ever successfully used multiline values in a cucumber data table. I have not been able to come up with a working solution.
I am working with smth like this:

Given i have a web service

When i make a request to "link" using filtering on:

```
|test1|"<"testvalue1">"|

|test2|"<"testvalue2">"|

|test3|"<"testvalue3">"|
```

Then i receive "<"response">"

And i receive a list of items "<"list">"

Examples:

```
|testvalue1 |testvalue2 |testvalue3 |list | response|

|value1    |value2   |value3   |a really long long long long long long long long long long list of items here| 200 |
```

What i would want to do is somehow split the list value on multiple lines, to improve readability.

Any working suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can use triple quotes ('''    blahblah multiline   ''') for passing additional data inside step. But not sure if it works in datatables

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but Cucumber does not seem to take into account cells that are not all on the same line, so it just says the datatable is missing cells.

Comment: Someone seems to have asked for it here https://github.com/cucumber-attic/gherkin/issues/52